# How to embed the App ID and Channel ID in a URL (Agora.io)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, video, webrtc, agora.io

So this is my problem statement: I want to establish a one-to-one communication (audio+video channels) using Agora.io for my Web App. While the connection is being established, there are two problems I'm running into:

1. How to ensure that the communications are one-to-one (private video call), and not one-to-many (conference).
2. I will be sending a link to the joinee to join the call. The host will establish the call using the App ID and the Channel ID. Is there any way to embed the App ID and the Channel ID in the URL, so that the joinee can join the video call just through one click?

I'm still new to this, would love the help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can embed these parameters as you would embed any other query parameter.

Example URL: https://example.com/?channel=cha123&appid=183432424242

In javascript:

```js
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let channel = params.get('name'); // is the string "cha123".
let appid = params.get('appid'); // is the string "183432424242"
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams